# Paypal shopping cart contents not showing on Transaction details page since Paypal site upgrade

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

PayPal made some changes to their site this week and since then the contents of the shopping cart are no longer showing on the Transaction details page, nor in the csv activity download. This issue applies to older transactions too - ones that were working before the site changes.

For info, the shopping cart details do still appear on the confirmation email sent by Paypal.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?